# Silverlight Coding Standards

Tags: silverlight

What are the coding standards we use for a standard Silverlight application following the MVVM pattern? Is there something available from Microsoft? The standard guidelines are for C# and i'm looking for something specific for Silverlight.

Thanks
Soni

Comment: you Should Also Prefared Prism patten

Answer (score 0):

MS has some docs about it,but not exactly looks like CLS-Compliance

Microsoft Pattens & Practices 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx

I don't think design patterns have strict rules we should obey. The point is solving the issue,but knowing how did it solved before us...

If you have a big project you may put your own rules.

Comment: Thanks Davut, I'll check it out as well. I will definitely think about defining some of the rules since I dont want the team to implement their own understanding of MVVM.